# Load and save multiple .fig files as .png files

Tags: matlab, command, export, matlab-figure

I have several MATLAB .fig files in a folder (say `folder/file1.fig` , `folder/file2.fig`,... etc.).
I want to export all of them to separate .png files. I know that I could open each of the .fig files in MATLAB and them simply export them one by one by hand, but this is very time-consuming, and I am looking for something more elegant, such as looping over all files in MATLAB and export them using MATLAB functions.

Is something like this possible in MATLAB? How should I go about this?

Comment: Give [`print`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) a try

Comment: Thanks for replying! Could you please elaborate a bit? I am still a bit new at matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
files = dir('.....');
for i = 1:length(files)
    currentfile = files(i).name;
    f = openfig(currentfile);
    print(f,'-dpng',[currentfile(1:end-3),'png']);
    close(f);
end
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can load the .fig files from the directory using [`openfig`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openfig.html) which will automatically open the figure and return the handle to the figure. You can then use [`saveas`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html) (or [`export_fig`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) from the File Exchange) to save the figure as a PNG.

```
folder = '/my/folder';

% Get all .fig files in the folder
files = dir(fullfile(folder, '*.fig'));
files = fullfile(folder, {files.name});

for k = 1:numel(files)
    % Get the filename
    [~, fname] = fileparts(files{k});

    % Open and display the .fig file
    hfig = openfig(files{k});

    % Save as a PNG file with the same name as the .fig file
    saveas(hfig, fullfile(folder, [fname, '.png']))

    % Close the figure again
    close(hfig)
end
```

If you don't want the figures constantly popping up as they open, you can specify the [visibility input](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openfig.html#inputarg_visibility) to `openfig` which will allow you to load and save the figure without ever having it render to the screen.

```
hfig = openfig(files{k}, 'invisible');
```

Comment: Is there any way to change the resolution as well?